# understanding boolean !array[i] in java

Tags: java, boolean, default

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/14array/CouponCollector.java.html

Okay, so from what I understand, if

```
boolean[] found = new boolean
```

is not initialized, it is assigned with the default boolean value, which is false. But since the negatron of false is true (`!found[val]`), how is it that this condition works when all of the boolean values are set to default (false)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: didn't you answer your own question there?

Comment: hmm if you say so, i think i see how i ended up thinking the way i did above. for example, in !found[val], i see it as !false (because of its default value). But now i'm guessing it doesn't work that way? idk, i'm having a hard time putting it into words. sry but i'm fairly new to this stuff :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no mystery here.  I think you just didn't read the code carefully.  Here are the relevant snippets and what they "mean".

```
    boolean[] found = new boolean[N];    // found[i] = true if card i has been collected
```

All elements of `found` are initially false.  (The comment is documenting the invariant for the `found` array.)

```
    if (!found[val]) valcnt++;
```

If `!found[val]` is true (i.e. it `found[val]` is still false) increment the counter ...

```
    found[val] = true;
```

... and set `found[val]` to true so that we don't count this val again.

Comment: THANK YOU! My mind just clicked after reading this. i feel so stupid now lol

Answer (score 2):

After the check, regardless of what happens, `found[val]` is set to `true`.  So `if (!found[val])` basically means "if i haven't seen this `val` before".

The end result is that `valcnt` ends up being the count of unique `val`s.

Answer (score 0):

There are false at first time.

```
int val = (int) (Math.random() * N);
```

this generates a random number so in this loop there may be generated more then one say fives. When 5 is generated at first time `found[5]` is false but in second time it's true so condition is false and `valcnt++;` won't be reached anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Because 'val' is a random integer between 0 and N-1. The same value might occur twice in the while loop and you want to update found at that index only once.